# What is the relation between Steins;Gate and Steins;Gate 0?

Tags: steins-gate

Is **Steins;Gate 0** a sequel to **Steins;Gate**? If not, what is common between the two and where do they deviate?

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Steins;Gate | Steins;Gate 0 |

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned by [one of the official translators](https://ask.fm/SciADV) that has worked on most of the Sci-fi Adventure series:<sup>[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/steinsgate/comments/37kkqi/a_question_about_steinsgate_0/crqger3)</sup>

> Steins;Gate Zero will not be a direct sequel, no. Remember when Okabe stabbed Kurisu and lost his resolve? Only to be revitalized once he received the Operation Skuld D-Mail from his future self? The Okabe in Epigraph and Zero is the Okabe that did not try again after killing Kurisu, the Okabe that gave up and resigned himself to misery.

- *Steins;Gate 0*, in spite of being marketed as the "true sequel" to *Steins;Gate*, does not take place after the ending of *Steins;Gate*. Even though it is canonical, it "takes place" just before the ending of Steins;Gate. Although, because it is about time travelling, all events in the narrative are relative, making the concepts of "before" and "after" somewhat meaningless. The events fit in a *logical sequence* before the "ending" of *Steins;Gate*, but in a casual sense rather than temporal.
- The story between the two is exactly the same upto (and including) Episode 22. It diverges in Episode 23 with the original story being covered in [Episode 23: Open the Steins Gate](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_23:_Open_the_Steins_Gate), and the alternate version, a *Steins;Gate 0* OVA, being covered in [Episode 23(β) Open the Missing Link](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/SG0_OVA:_Episode_23(%CE%B2)_Open_the_Missing_Link). As mentioned [on the Wikia](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/SG0_OVA:_Episode_23(%CE%B2)_Open_the_Missing_Link):

> In this story, after killing Makise Kurisu, Okabe Rintarou gives up and accepts her funeral fate.
>
> The main difference between this and the original episode 23 is that this Okabe      does not receive the Video-Mail from himself. **He** will go on to eventually create Operation Skuld and the Video-Mail, helping S;G Okabe thwart world line convergence and successfully avert both Kurisu's death and WWIII in order to enter the Steins;Gate world line of 1.048596% divergence.

---

**TL;DR:** In concise, as put on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/steinsgate/comments/37kkqi/a_question_about_steinsgate_0/):

> It follows the world where Okabe tried to save Kurisu, but stabbed her instead. It is the worldline in which Okabe doesn't get the "deceive yourself" message from himself, but it is most likely the one that sends that message.